# Active Directory User info Ldap SQL query ThumbNailPhoto

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to import active directory data using SQL query below. But for the thumbNailPhoto I am getting a truncation error. Please help.

OLE DB provider 'ADsDSOObject' for linked server 'ADSI' returned truncated data for column '[ADsDSOObject].thumbnailPhoto'. The actual data length is 6846 and truncated data length is 4000

```
 SELECT employeeID,
displayName,
sAMAccountName,
sn,
givenName,
title,
department,
mail,
ipPhone,
employeeNumber,
telephoneNumber,
mobile,
facsimileTelephoneNumber,
info,
accountExpires,
thumbNailPhoto
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,
'<LDAP://xxxx>;
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user));
employeeID,displayName,sAMAccountName,sn,givenName,title,department,mail,ipPhone,employeeNumber,telephoneNumber,mobile,facsimileTelephoneNumber,info,accountExpires,thumbNailPhoto,
cn,ADsPath;subtree')
```

Tried with SSIS data flow. thumbNailPhoto instead of actual data I see this in the destination table "System.Byte[]"

Has anyone done something similar and able to get it right?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW - I know not much help, but I've run into this before and the best I've been able to come up with is that there is a 4K limit on columns in the SQL Server interface to ADSI...  Unfortunately I can't test more because all the images in our AD are < 4K and I don't have access to load one bigger...